# Can I use In5 to to export InDesign files to Html5 that can be loaded into Baker Framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, html

I'm looking to use the Baker Framework to create a magazine app in Xcode, but I have no experience with HTML5.

I do, however, have experience creating interactive documents in InDesign.  I would like advice as to whether this is an appropriate workflow for what I'd like to do.

- Design Interactive Magazine in InDesign CS6 (This would include animations, buttons, audio and scrolling text)
- Export it to HTML5 using [Ajar's In5](http://ajarproductions.com/pages/products/in5/)
- Load the HTML5 export into [Baker Framework](http://bakerframework.com/) and continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using In5 to export my magazine and it works like a charm. However, I think you need to code all your animations in the files exported.

If you don't know HTML5, I recommend to take a look at Laker (http://www.lakercompendium.com/). In "How to use", they have a lot of code that will help you.

Comment: Support for native InDesign animation has been added to in5 version 2.